# How can I get actual page ID in yii

Tags: php, sql, frameworks, yii

I absolutely new to yii framework, but now, I should have to repair a page. :(((
How can I get the page ID in a simpliest way?
I storm my brain for about 2 hours in tha simply question. 
Could somebody help me please?

Thx

Comment: Somebody have to say, that in yii the pages represented by a name and they isnt has an integer id value.

Comment: Clearly your English isn't your language, but we need a bit more info - code, errors, etc. to help. To get the controller or action id's you can use `$this->getId()` or `$this->getAction()->getId()` see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#getId-detail) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAction#getId-detail)

Answer (score 1):

ID of the controller: `$this->getId();`

The controller ID that is prefixed with the module ID: `$this->getUniqueId();`

ID of the action: `$this->getAction()->getId();`